# Average of a column by unique pair of another columns

Tags: pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a pandas dataframe as below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': {0: 365, 1: 365, 2: 365, 3: 365, 4: 356, 5: 261, 6: 240, 7: 238},
 'end': {0: 240, 1: 261, 2: 356, 3: 238, 4: 365, 5: 365, 6: 365, 7: 365},
 'value': {0: 585, 1: 567, 2: 191, 3: 186, 4: 196, 5: 545, 6: 564, 7: 184}})
```

Here's what the dataframe looks like,

```
    start   end     value   
1   365     240     585     
2   365     261     567     
3   365     356     191     
4   365     238     186
5   356     365     196     
6   261     365     545     
7   240     365     564     
8   238     365     184
```

There are four unique pairs of start-end. And i want a dataframe with average of value for each of this unique pairs. output dataframe would like below :

```
        start   end     value   
    1   365     240     574.5   
    2   365     261     556     
    3   365     356     193.5   
    4   365     238     185
```

I know i can get the number of occurence of unique pair by using `groupby` and `size` functions, but cannot thing of a way to apply average on the `value` column for each unique pair. Does `grouper` function from Pandas can be used for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to sort start and end and then groupby-average on these two columns:

```
df[["start", "end"]] = -np.sort(-df.iloc[:, :2], axis=1)
df.groupby(["start", "end"]).value.mean().reset_index()

# out:
   start  end  value
0    365  238  185.0
1    365  240  574.5
2    365  261  556.0
3    365  356  193.5
```